# How to infer schema in the Avro header in apache_beam python?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, avro

I have an AVRO file, and the file has schema in the header. I am trying to fetch the schema from the header using apache_beam Pyhotn SDK. But unable to get that. Any help or direction will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider these 2 approaches to run the beam pipeline to infer schema from avro files using Python.

**Option 1:**

```py
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

schema = avro.schema.parse(open("avro.avsc", "rb").read())

records = p | 'Read from Avro' >> ReadFromAvro(known_args.input)

# Write the file
records | 'Write to Avro' >> WriteToAvro(known_args.output, schema=schema, file_name_suffix='.avro')

# Run the pipeline
result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

**Option 2:** Use python `with` keyword to execute the pipeline:

```py
schema = avro.schema.parse(open("avro.avsc", "rb").read())

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    records = p | ReadFromAvro(known_args.input)
    records | WriteToAvro(known_args.output, schema=schema, file_name_suffix='.avro')
```

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas).